# irr: Krippendorf's Alpha with non-numeric classifications (Warning Message)

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate `Krippendorf's Alpha` using the `irr::kripp.alpha` function.

My input data consists of non-numeric classifications (e.g., "1.a", "1.b" etc.). When using `kripp.alpha()` I get the following warning message

```
Warning message:
In kripp.alpha(as.matrix(p8)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

It seems that the function -- nevertheless -- works fine.

Anyhow, I tried to get rid of the warning message by using the following procedure:

```
input <- data.frame(coder1=c("3.a","3.a","3.b.ii","3.b.ii","3.a","3.a","4.d","4.d"),
                    coder2=c("3.b","3.a","3.b.i","3.b.ii","3.a","3.a","4.d","4.d"))

# Gives the Warning Message
kripp.alpha(as.matrix(t(input)))

input <- unlist(input)

#Replace levels (strings) with unique numeric values
levels(input) <- 1:length(levels(input))

#Transform back into matrix format that kripp.alpha uses
input <- matrix(input, nrow=2)

kripp.alpha(input)
```

This works fine. However, it is quite cumbersome for such an easy task. Is there a simpler method? Can somebody explain why the function gives the warning message when using non-numeric classification values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had contact with the package maintainer. The `kripp.alpha()` function expects numeric classifications as input. They may fix it in one of the next package updates.

So either you live with that warning message or you use the solution posted above.